# VueJs component's style not updated in production

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, deployment, vue-component

I deployed a vue app which comes with Laravel on a shared hosting, but now I updated a component's style and then wrote the production command again .. after that, I redeployed/updated "public/app.css" and the component with the old one on my hosting .. but it did not updated anything I did!!
any ideas?

or, anyone can help me understand how to edit/update styles from development to the shared hosting?

Comment: it might be just the browser cache, but I can't tell for sure. have you checked that?

Comment: I checked it.. not the reason!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be that your server has an internal cache which you should force to be cleaned

For example AWS-S3 with Cloudfront sometimes changes take time to be seen

The way to verify this, is by checking with the inspect element the network tab, open the css to confirm that the new style you put is there